# MySQL insert into table doesn't insert

Tags: database, insert

I'm new to PHP and MYSQL trying to learn and having an ongoing project. I'm following on a code tutorial on profile pictures and I'm trying a way to upload multiple pictures uploaded by a specific user ID. It goes fine on uploading into the file destination but the problem I'm having is getting it stored into the database.

Here's my upload.php

```
<?php
session_start();

//connection to database
include_once('dbh.inc.php');
$id = $_SESSION['u_id'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//getting the file
$file = $_FILES['file'];

//file info
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

$fileExt = explode('.',$fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

//allowed formats
$allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png');

//check if the format uploaded is allowed
if(in_array($fileActualExt,$allowed)){
    if($fileError===0){
        if($fileSize < 1000000){
          //setting up for a new file name
          $fileNameNew = $id.".".$fileName.".".$fileActualExt;
          $fileDestination = 'uploads/' . $fileNameNew;
          move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$fileDestination);
          //inserting into database
          $sql = "INSERT INTO imageuploads (image,uid_fk) VALUES ('$fileNameNew','$id')";
          mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
          header("Location: ../artsy.php?uploadsuccess");
        }else{
            echo "This file is too large";
        }
    }else{
        echo "There was an error uploading this file";
    }
}else{
    echo "You cannot upload files of this type";
}
}
```

The imageuploads database contains "img_id" which is auto-incrementing, "image" which is a varchar that will contain the new file name, and "uid_fk" which is a foreign key id that is referencing the user ID.

I don't receive any errors but it doesn't create a new row, however when I run it in SQL localhost it's fine and creates a new row.

Comment: If you don't receive the error may be is because you didn't add some errors check like mysql errors on return after the queries, may be too you didn't check the logs server i mean Apache log or mysql log PHP log ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example how to upload multiple images: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRwMjRNQx6k

Here code how upload multiple images (working example):

```
    <?php
session_start();

// dont show errors
error_reporting(0);

// allow big files
ini_set('post_max_size','400M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','200M');

// database
$mdatabase = 'test';
$muser = 'root';
$mpass = 'toor';
$mhost = 'localhost';
$mport = 3306;

// connect to mysql with PDO function
function Conn(){
    global $mhost,$mport,$muser,$mpass,$mdatabase;
    $connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.$mhost.';port='.$mport.';dbname='.$mdatabase.';charset=utf8', $muser, $mpass);
    // don't cache query
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    // show warning text
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    // throw error exception
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // don't colose connecion on script end
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, false);
    // set utf for connection utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci 
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
    return $connection;
}

function saveLink($link, $id = 0){  
    global $db; // allow mysql connection from global variables
    if (!empty($link)) {
        $link = htmlentities($link,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
        $r = $db->query("INSERT INTO imageuploads (image,uid_fk) VALUES ('$link','$id')");
        // last inserted id if you had auto increment primary key id (int or bigint)
        $id = $db->lastInsertId();
        return $id;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

// db connection
$db = Conn();

//connection to database
$gid = $_SESSION['u_id'] = 777;


//inserting into database
// $sql = "INSERT INTO imageuploads (image,uid_fk) VALUES ('$fileNameNew','$id')";

// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($_FILES);
// 1 MB = 1024 KB = 1 048 576 Bytes = 8 388 608 bitów
$maxsizemb = 1024 * 1024 * 8;
$i = 1;
mkdir("galeria/".$gid, 0755, true);
foreach ($_FILES['files']['type'] as $key => $value) {
    if(($value == "image/png") || ($value == "image/jpg") || ($value == "image/gif") || ($value == "image/jpeg")){
        //echo $value.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];      
        $size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key]; // bytes
        $name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];         
        $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key]);
        $ext = end($temporary);
        if ($size < $maxsizemb) {
            $fileto = "galeria/".$gid."/".md5(microtime()).".".$ext;
            move_uploaded_file($tmp, $fileto);
            saveLink($fileto, $gid);
            $all[$i] = $fileto; 
        }else{
            echo 'Zbyt duży plik (max 1 MB)';
        }
    }
    $i++;       
}
?>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Only JPG</label>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="true" accept="image/*"><br>
    <!-- or all files -->
    <label>All images</label>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="true"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="UPLOAD">
</form>
```

And mysql table (database name: test)

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.3
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Czas generowania: 25 Wrz 2017, 07:49
-- Wersja serwera: 10.1.25-MariaDB
-- Wersja PHP: 5.6.31

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Baza danych: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struktura tabeli dla tabeli `imageuploads`
--

CREATE TABLE `imageuploads` (
  `id` bigint(21) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `uid_fk` bigint(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indeksy dla zrzutów tabel
--

--
-- Indexes for table `imageuploads`
--
ALTER TABLE `imageuploads`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT dla tabeli `imageuploads`
--
ALTER TABLE `imageuploads`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(21) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```